# Label and sublabel for theorem

Tags: theorems, labels

In my text file, I am using a `theorem` environment (from the `amsthm` package), that contains two parts (for two different cases). The theorem is often referenced as a whole, so I need a global label, but each case is proven on its own, and often referenced specifically, and therefore I also need specific "sublabel". The structure would look as follow :

```
\begin{theorem}\label{main_thm}
    This is the main theorem, with two cases,
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First Case \label{first_case}
        \item Second Case \label{first_case}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

The first label follows the environment numbering (enforced by section - I cannot change it), while the second would only reference the item number. So that for instance with later references :

- `see theorem \ref{main_thm}` would appear as "see theorem 4.3"
- `see theorem \ref{first_case}` would appear as "see theorem (a)" making it impossible to reference in later sections.

Is there anyway to make thinks clearer? setting some kind of subtheorem, or sublabeling. Idealy a futur reference would look as

- `see theorem \ref{main_thm}` would appear as "see theorem 4.3"
- `see theorem \ref{first_case}` would appear as "see theorem 4.3a"

In this site, I found some question on subtheorem, but they always reference a hierarchical numbering of lemmas, rather than two part of one theorem. And the `sublabel` package split the label as 4a,4b,4c, but does not allow for 4,4a,4b...

Comment: One idea could be to stack your `\ref{}` calls i.e. `\ref{main_thm}\ref{first_case}` which would result in `4.3a`.

Comment: True, this is not really "clean", but it sure works, and it's very simple! so simple I had not even thought about it! :) I'll use it if there are no good other solutions

Comment: You can load `enumitem` and code `\begin{enumerate[label=(alph*), ref=\ref{main_thm}alph*]`

Comment: Worked perfectly, with the small typo `\alph*` instead of `alph*`. You want to make that an answer? Otherwise I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the package `enumitem`, this

```
\begin{theorem}\label{main_thm}
    This is the main theorem, with two cases,
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), ref=\ref{main_thm}\alph*]
        \item First Case \label{first_case}
        \item Second Case \label{first_case}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

work as intended.